# $k$-variety and function field equivalence in the case where $k$ is not algebraically closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I know that if $k$ is algebraically closed, then we can show that there is an equivalence of categories between the $k$-varieties and the extension of $k$ finitely generated as $k$-algebra. But, when $k$ is not, but is a finite field for example, can we say that we have the same result modulo the fact that we ask the extension of $k$ finitely generated as $k$-algebra to have its full field of constant over $k$ ?

I tried to demonstrate it, but I'm struggling showing that the functor is essentially surjective. 
If I take $K/k$ such an extension, we can find some $X=\operatorname{Spec}(k[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(f))$ which has $K$ as function field, $(f)$ prime in $k[T_1, \dots, T_n]$ but not necessarly in $\overline{k}[T_1, \dots, T_n]$. So, as we ask a variety over $k$ to be some $\operatorname{Spec}(\overline{k}[T_1, \dots, T_s]/I)$ (or the same with $\operatorname{Proj}$ for projective ones) where $I$ can be generated by polynomial with coefficients in $k$ and $I$ a prime ideal, It doesn't work.

Someone could help me ?

Thank you !

Edit : As ask in comment, here, a $k$-variety is either affine, in which case it's defined as some $Spec(\overline{k}[T_1, \dots, T_n]/I)$ which is irreducible and where $I$ is such that we can choose generators with coefficients in $k$ (in particular, it permits to consider $Spec(k[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(I\cap k[T_1, \dots, T_n))$; or either projective, in which case we just replace from what is above the word "Spec" by "Proj", and where $I$ is generating by homogenous polynomial (which can be chosen with coefficients in $k$ again).

Comment: This correspondence you speak of is false as stated: $\Bbb A^1$ minus any finite collection of closed points is an affine variety with function field $k(t)$, and it is not possible for these varieties to be isomorphic for different numbers of removed points. Do you perhaps mean $k$-varieties up to birational equivalence? (This is also sensitive to your definition of variety - could you include it in the post, please?)

Comment: @KReiser I have edited my post in order to explain what definition of $k$-variety I'm using here. How $\mathbb{A}^1$ minus finite collection of closed points could be an affine variety ? I mean, maybe it's the case, but just like that, I don't see why.

Comment: $k[T]$, the coordinate algebra of $\Bbb A^1_k$, is a PID. This means the ideal of every closed point $c$ is generated by a monic irreducible polynomial $p_c(T)$. If you want to remove some finite number of points $\{c_1,\cdots,c_n\}$, this corresponds to the affine scheme with coordinate algebra $k[T,p_{c_1}(T)^{-1},\cdots,p_{c_n}(T)^{-1}]\cong k[T,U]/(U\cdot (\prod_{i} p_{c_i}(T)) -1)$. This is a generalization of the common trick of viewing $\Bbb A^1\setminus 0$ as $V(xy-1)$ inside $\Bbb A^2$.